Betaflight, ELRS CRC8 calculation for CRSF packets
I've been going over the spec of the CRSF protocol which is pretty simple:
All packets are in the CRSF format [sync] [len] [type] [payload] [crc8] with a maximum total size of 64 bytes. CRC8 using poly 0xD5, includes all bytes from type (buffer[2]) to end of payload.
I am looking at raw packets from the receiver and no matter what I do, I can not reach the same checksum result. See raw packets below (italic is the data used to calculate CRC8):
C8 18 16 AE 70 85 2B 68 F1 8B 9F FC E2 17 7F F8 05 F8 28 08 00 00 4C 7C E2 63
C8 18 16 C0 03 1F FA 80 F7 8B 9F FC E2 17 7F F8 05 F8 28 08 00 00 4C 7C E2 9C
I've used multiple CRC8 calculators with different settings, but nothing works.
Any ideas?
